# "Although" and "even though" in a single sentence

Tags: concessives

Can we use *although* and *even though* in a single sentence?

For example:

> Although significant inroads have been made in recent decades, women continue to be underrepresented in fields related to science, technology, engineering, and math (STEM), even though more women than men now attend college.

If not, how can I make this sentence clear?

Comment: This is probably more about style than language... welcome to ELL!

Comment: Yes, we can, and your sentence is a perfect example of it.

Comment: Women, long underrepresented in STEM professions, have made significant inroads in recent decades. *If the percentages of male and female students who are interested in STEM professions remain constant*,  we can expect the number of women in these professions to increase marginally and move towards parity with men, because today more women than men are attending college.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of two "concessive" clauses is not in itself ungrammatical; but putting them in this order gives the impression that you are just setting down your ideas in the order in which they occur to you, without stopping to consider their relationships.

In the first place, it is unclear how we are to take the final clause. Is the new preponderance of women in the college population **evidence** of the inroads that have been made, or is it **background** against which the inroads must be measured?

In the second place, it is wholly unclear what is being measured here. You introduce three terms:

- *underrepresentation*, which we may infer asserts some deficiency in women's participation in the STEM fields.
- *inroads*, which we may infer asserts some increase over time in women's participation in the STEM fields.
- *more women than men now attend college*, which we may infer asserts some increase over time in the proportion of women in the college population.

But we have no idea how these terms are measured, or whether they are commensurable. Are "inroads" and "underrepresentation" measured against the general population or against the college population? Are they even measured against the same baseline? And of greatest importance, how do the two measures of change compare? Is the proportion of women in STEM fields increasing faster than the proportion of women in the college population, slower, or at the same rate?

Just by way of illustration, here are two completely different sets of facts which your sentence might represent (the numbers are completely invented):

> Significant inroads have been made since 1992: the number of college women in STEM fields has increased by 67%, and they are now 50% of the students in these fields. Over the same period, however, their presence in the college population increased faster, by 75%, and women are now 60% of all students. Consequently, they are still underrepresented in the STEM fields by a factor of 50%:60%.
>
> Significant inroads have been made since 1992: the number of college women in STEM fields has increased by 30%, and they are now 40% of the students in these fields. Over the same period, however, the proportion of women in the total college population increased even faster, by 33%, and today they are 60% of all students. Women are not only still significantly underrepresented in the STEM fields proportional to their number in the college population (40%:60%), the proportion of women electing to study in the STEM fields has actually declined slightly, from 6.67% to 6.5%.

Having introduced two dynamic measures, the changes in the proportion of women in college and the proportion of women in STEM fields, it is essential that you describe them in commensurable terms and that you give some account of their relative movement.

Comment: Well, it's incumbent upon you to do that if you are writing a peer-reviewed paper, but if you're a journalist writing for a newspaper, the editor would throw out your thorough, accurate article in favor of the original, imprecise-but-much-more-digestible summary.  Audience, audience, audience.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Those are not rewrites - they're possible underlying facts which the sentence should reflect. We have no way of rewriting OP's sentence because we don't what it is intended to mean.

Comment: Agreed. And I do appreciate your insightful analysis. Too bad most journalists don't have your skills in logic.